# proof verification on the distance of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

let $A\subseteq  \mathbb{R}$ and  $\delta (A)=\sup\left \{  {| d(x,y)| :x,y\epsilon A} \right \}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ cont. if $\delta (A)<+\infty $ then $\delta (f(A))<+\infty$

my solution,

we know that $\delta (A)=\delta (\bar{A})\Rightarrow \delta (\bar{A})<+\infty $ ,since $\bar{A}$ is closed and bounded we have that is compact ,now $f$ is cont. and we know that $f(\bar{A})$ is also bounded so $\delta (f(\bar{A}))<+\infty$ but

$\delta (f(A)) \subseteq  \delta(f(\bar{A}))$(is = true??)

we have that  $\delta (f(A))<+\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $f(A) \subseteq f(\bar A)$; you should be able to convince yourself that in general, if $P \subseteq Q$, then $f(P) \subseteq f(Q)$.

From this, it follows that $\delta(f(A)) \leq \delta(f(\bar A))$.

Comment: Even more: since $f$ is continuous, $f(\overline A) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$, and then $\delta(f(\overline A)) \leq \delta(\overline{f(A)}) = \delta(f(A))$.